# Could not find attribute 'onmousedown' VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2003, onmousedown

Why does Visual studio give this message in the task list when I use "onmousedown" on an asp:button:

> Could not find attribute 'onmousedown'
>   of element button

Surely it does exist. After all, it works! The same thing happens for "onmouseup"

Is there a way to suppress these messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN those aren't valid attributes on an asp:Button tag: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx#DeclarativeSyntax

So how does it work? Not sure, I guess it is inheriting them from WebControl or Control.

Is there a good reason why you can't use Click or Command handlers (OnClick="MethodName" or OnCommand="MethodName")?

Comment: I can't use onclick or oncommand because they're already used for other purposes.

Comment: It sounds like you might be trying to do too much with a single button if you need OnMouseDown, OnMouseUp, OnClick and OnCommand!

Comment: Maybe so. But that doesn't explain why "onmousedown" isn't found, but still works. I'm not really looking for a work-around.

Comment: @Urbycoz: Can't help there I'm afraid.

Comment: Much appreciated all the same.